# How to have terraform import all of the "already exists" resources automatically?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

When I run `terraform apply -auto-approve` I get the following error:

```
Error: A resource with the ID "/subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/RG-SCUSTFStorage" already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State. Please see the resource documentation for "azurerm_resource_group" for more information.
```

I underestand that I need to run `terraform import` to import the resource to my worksapce. The problem is that I need to specify the resource id for all of the missing resources one at a time.

Is any way to have `terraform import` import all of the "already exists " resources automatically witout entering the resource IDs one at a time?

Comment: i thought about creating such a tool. `terraform import-all` looks like it could be useful, i ran into this several times and looking up syntax and manually importing one-by-one is always a pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to import Azure resources then [aztfy](https://github.com/Azure/aztfy) is the recommended tool as it is natively from Azure.

It does generate the terraform code, additionally, it has a feature where you can import the azure resource group, it automatically imports and generates config for the resources that the resource group is holding.
Not to mention but the tool gives you a nice terminal-based-UI experience.

For other hyperscalers, there are two choices.

- [terracognita](https://github.com/cycloidio/terracognita) : can generate modules too as per their docs.
- [terraformer](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer) : Developed by Google people but not official product.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you only can import the existing resources one by one with the resource IDs manually:

> The import command doesn’t automatically generate the configuration to
> manage the infrastructure, though. Because of this, importing existing
> infrastructure into Terraform is a multi-step process.

More details [here](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/state-import?utm_source=WEBSITE&utm_medium=WEB_IO&utm_offer=ARTICLE_PAGE&utm_content=DOCS). I will suggest you use [remote state storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/store-state-in-azure-storage) for all the Terraform scripts before deployment. If you do not have the state file that contains all the deployed resources, then you only can import them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a native way in Terraform to import already existing resources, however, there are a couple of tools available that allow you to not only import the resources but also generate Terraform code for them if it doesn't already exist.

For Azure, the best tool to use is Azure-built [AZtfy](https://github.com/Azure/aztfy). A tool to bring your existing Azure resources under the management of Terraform.

Another tool to that can be used to import Azure resources is Google Cloud  [Terraformer](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer) which supports Azure.